# What is "einem neugierigen Journalisten" in the dativ plural form?

Tags: article, dative, grammatical-number

"einem neugierigen Journalisten". I know that "einem" is incorrect and so ist "einen".  But for the life of me, I cannot figure out what the correct dativ plural form of this should be!  What am I not realizing?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. »Ich gebe **einem neugierigen Journalisten** ein Interview« is absolutely correct and high-quality standard German. The bold marked part is **dative singular**. There is no plural in this sentence. Next time please post **complete sentences,** not just 3 words without any context.

Answer (score 11):

**Einem** is singular, because it means *one*. German has no indefinite plural article.

Indefinite article:

> Wem haben Sie das gesagt? – Ein**em** neugierig**en** Journalist**en**. *(Singular männlich)*
>
> Wem haben Sie das gesagt? – Neugierig**en** Journalist**en**. *(Plural)*

Definite article:

> Wem haben Sie das gesagt? – De**m** neugierig**en** Journalist**en**. *(Singular männlich)*
>
> Wem haben Sie das gesagt? – De**n** neugierig**en** Journalist**en**. *(Plural)*

Comment: You could consider the pronoun "vielen" as an indefinite plural. It is often used as a replacement.

Comment: *Einige* works, too.

Comment: "Welche" as well

Comment: Not to forget "Mehreren" and "etlichen".

Comment: Indefinite is only the solution in the answer. All your other comments are suggesting specificity in characterizing the journalists. I won't go into details, as this is a comment, but bear in mind that those words are not a replacement for the missing plural indefinite article. To find out the meaning of those words, I suggest a new question ;)

Comment: @thymaro The replacement should only be used to help a learner fix the case on "Journalisten". Once it helped to see it's dative plural, you can cross it out again and forget about it.